# Why is my bottom .row class include everything in the previous .row class?

Tags: css, html, wordpress

The site in question is http://new.technoheads.org.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the bottom .row class is so large. Chrome's Inspector highlights everything, including all the contents of the previous .row class. Adding a background color to that specific div confirms that. I can move it outside of the .page div that it's in and put it in its own, but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` somewhere (see  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.technoheads.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 ).  Things might become clearer once that's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. Add this to your CSS:

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

(via [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/))

Than add the `group` class to your `row` divs. E.g:

```
<div class="row group"> ... </div>
```

Also, [you should read this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) to get a better understanding of floats.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just add them to the .row?

Comment: So you can reuse the `.group` class on other elements that contain floats.